# Implementing a custom transport protocol - Linux kernel

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, kernel

I am currently working on a school project, to develop a custom transport protocol that would function right above the data link layer in the OSI model.

For the last couple of months I've been working on different projects involving hacking the Linux kernel and I've done quite an extensive reading of the Linux Kernel Development book so this is not all new to me.

What I would really like is some help regarding what documentation should I read so that I could get a glimpse of how the Linux's network internals work and maybe work more efficiently on my assignment.

Comment: What are the protocol requirements?  What language are you planning to use? What are you planning to do that UDP, TCP, or SCTP have not already done?

Comment: @Mike - it's a school project, what does that matter?!

Comment: @Alnitak, sure requirements don't matter for a school project.  You know better

Comment: He asked for pointers to documentation, not a networking masterclass.

Comment: @Alnitak, doesn't it help to know which documentation to provide?  How much does he know about networking already?  What specifically will this protocol do?  All basic things before you go reading the vast library of information about linux networking, or would you rather just throw [Richard Steven's 1994 classic](http://www.amazon.com/TCP-Illustrated-Vol-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0201633469/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1304794152&sr=8-1) and [Wright's Book](http://www.amazon.com/TCP-IP-Illustrated-Vol-Implementation/dp/020163354X/ref=pd_sim_b_1) at him and get a quick accept?

Comment: Transport protocol right above the data link layer?  You sure?

Answer (score 0):

There's an ancient article about [Network Buffers and Memory Management](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1312) by Alan Cox. More recently, David S. Miller has written a bit about [Linux Networking](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem), and, of course, several universities have produced documentation of varying quality about Linux network internals.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this Book : understanding linux network internals by christian
And Linux kernel networking , implementation and Theory by Rami Rosen